# Using InputMask in QML

Tags: qml

I have a small display window, that should hold an InputMask like "0000.00". When clicking on the Number-Buttons from 0 to 9, the display should show the respective numbers, for example: 0345.89
Here is my code:

```
TextInput {
    id: displayNumbers6Text
    cursorVisible: true
    focus: true
    validator: RegExpValidator {
        regExp: /[0-9]+/
    }
    inputMask: "0000.00"
    maximumLength: 7
}
```

And for the Buttons:

```
Button {
     width: parent.width*0.3
     height: parent.height*0.15
     buttonColor: "#000000"
     MouseArea {
          anchors.fill: parent
          onClicked: {
                displayNumbers6Text.text = "1"
          }
     }
}
```

But it doesn't function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you assign `text` property, you reset this value to "1".
If what you are trying is to insert a value when clicking on a button, you can try this :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 200 

    TextInput {
        id: displayNumbers6Text
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.5

        cursorVisible: true
        focus: true
        validator: DoubleValidator {
        }
        inputMask: "0000.00"
        maximumLength: 7

        function appendNum(num) {
            var dotPos = text.indexOf(".");
            if (dotPos == 4)
                text += num;
            else
                text = text.substr(0, dotPos) + num + text.substr(dotPos);
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width*0.3
        height: parent.height*0.15
        anchors.top: displayNumbers6Text.bottom
        color: "black"
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log(displayNumbers6Text.text);
                displayNumbers6Text.appendNum("1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- You can use DoubleValidator instead of a general RegexValidator, it will be more readable.
- I add an appendNum function to `TextInput` to insert a value at the end of the text string. Note that the dot character is always in the string, beacause of the `inputMask` you set

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. I have just one error: when clicking the numbers, they position themselves not in left-to-right or right-to-left order, but seemingly irrationally: first on the left of the point, then after clicking on the second button, the first number moves to the right, making space for the second number, and so on. How can I let them all stay on the same place?

Comment: @user3069706 Well spot, I fix little mistake concerning substring delimitations